# Write to single channel pixelbuffer in OpenGl ES 2.0 for iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, iphone-4

I am writing an iOS video applicaion using OpenGL ES 2.0 to do image processing.

My input and output format of the video is YUV 4:2:0 which is the native pixel format for most devices after the iPhone 3GS. For the A5 processor and higher I simply create a luma texture and a chroma texture and I attach them to the offscreen framebuffer. I create my texutre as following:

```
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                   _videoTextureCache,
                                                   pixelBuffer,
                                                   NULL,
                                                   GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                   GL_RED_EXT,
                                                   (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0),
                                                   (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0),
                                                   GL_RED_EXT,
                                                   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                   0,
                                                   &lumaTexture);
```

and then I attach it to the program like:

```
glActiveTexture([self getTextureUnit:textureUnit]);
glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(texture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(texture));
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
if(uniform != -1)
{
    glUniform1i(uniforms[uniform], textureUnit);
}
```

In my shader I can then simply do:

```
gl_FragColor.r = texture2D(SamplerY, textureRead).r;
```

to assign a luma value to the buffer and save the resulting video frame to disk.

Unfortunately I am running into problems for the iPhone 4 as this isn't using the A5 processor and consequently the `GL_RED_EXT` isn't supported.

I have then tried to figure out a way to write to a 1 channel luma buffer in OpenGL ES, but keep running into problems. I tried simply changing the `GL_RED_EXT` to `GL_LUMINANCE` but found out that it isn't possible to write to `GL_LUMINANCE`.

I then tried registering a color attachment and a depth attachment as:

```
GLuint colorRenderbuffer;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGB8_OES, (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(renderData.destinationPixelBuffer, 0), (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(renderData.destinationPixelBuffer, 0));
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                              GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);

GLuint depthRenderbuffer;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(renderData.destinationPixelBuffer, 0), (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(renderData.destinationPixelBuffer, 0));
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
                              GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
```

Writing to the depth buffer in my fragment shader:

```
gl_FragDepth.z = texture2D(SamplerY, textureRead).r;
```

And then writing the result to the pixel buffer as:

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(renderData.destinationPixelBuffer, 0), (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(renderData.destinationPixelBuffer, 0), GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(renderData.destinationPixelBuffer, 0));
```

But again I read in the specs that OpenGL ES 2.0 does not support writing directly to the depth buffer.

So I am left with no obvious way to create a single channel color attachment and I am not sure how I could write to a RGB color attachment and only copy one channel to my pixel buffer.

Sorry for the long post, just wanted to give as much information as possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to keep the Y and UV channels separate through your OpenGL ES processing, and not simply convert them to RGB as is done in most cases? I'm not sure that the benefits of maintaining YUV content throughout will offset the disadvantages of having to render the scene twice for Y and UV. The only situation this might benefit would be AV Foundation movie recording at the end, but even there it seems to do a good job with BGRA frames.

Comment: Hello @BradLarson, actually if you are holding few frames in memory for smooth video recording, there might be a benefit in holding YUV420 frames as they occupy significantly less memory. Any ideas how to render YUV frame to YUV in a single pass ?

Comment: @DeepakSharma - OpenGL ES textures are RGBA, so you'd need to maintain separate planes for the Y and UV throughout. Again, you'd either need to perform multiple render passes or use OpenGL ES 3.0 and have multiple render targets. All of your fragment shaders would need to be written to support these separate planes at each stage.

Comment: Thanks @BradLarson, I can go for GLES 3.0 for 64 bit devices, but for older devices, do you see any performance loss in 2 render passes for Y & UV planes compared to single pass for BGRA sample buffers ?

Comment: @DeepakSharma - Yes, you will notice a loss in performance from that, up to a doubling in render time. This will depend on the complexity of your operation, of course.

Comment: Very old post and I realized I never answered it after solving this issue. The motivation to use YUV wasn't 100% for performance reasons as @BradLarson mentioned OpenGL works in simple RGBA colorspace. The motivation was that some of the video processing steps I used were better suited in YUV space.

So how I ended up solving this was to use GL_LUMINANCE and GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA instead of RED and RG if the extensions aren't available. I would then add a step after my render passes to use glReadPixels to manually copy the pixels into the expected format for my preallocated pixelbuffers.

Comment: Another reason was that some of the new APIs I used in AVFoundation didn't support anything but YUV colorspace at the time of writing.

Later re-wrote the whole framework in metal and was at least 10x easier and 10 times as little code required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So how I ended up solving this was to use GL_LUMINANCE and GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA instead of RED and RG if the extensions aren't available. I would then add a step after my render passes to use glReadPixels to manually copy the pixels into the expected format of my preallocated pixelbuffers.